# Plsql block in process

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Plsql code in process:

I want to join two procedure according to my item selection in apex page process:

- `P1_text_field` - if I enter some email id then the procedure 1 should work
- `P2_select_list` - if I enter somthing in this field then procedure 2 should work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to write some conditional PL/SQL in a submit process:

```
if :P1_TEXT_FIELD is not null then
  procedure_1;
elsif :P2_SELECT_LIST is not null then
  procedure_2;
end if;
```

This will only be run when the page is submitted, which could be when the user clicks a button or triggered by the item itself (see item properties).